# Javascript error - extensions::SafeBuiltins:82

Tags: javascript

[image]

**Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**

Everything works good but I noticed there is an error in console.
Does anyone know what is this?

Comment: If _Everything works good_ then why not party:)

Comment: it seems like your extension is crashing. did you try to disable it?

Comment: Emre, Thanks!  I just check my extensions and found this extension cause  it http://i.imgur.com/wVYGrid.png , do you want to post answer to get reputaion?

Comment: I ran into this problem today, same extension x.x

Comment: Same extension for me as well, @TerryLin you might want to consider writing an answer to your own question that calls this plugin out as the guilty one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have the same problem with me, try to disable extensions. For example, when I disable "Open SEO Stats", the error message is disappeared.

[image]

Comment: Power of StackOverflow! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of Open SEO Stats. The Page Speed module of Open SEO Stats extension is not working on Google Chrome 44 and causing error message "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation - extensions::SafeBuiltins:82" in console window.

This bug is caused by Google Chrome 44 issue. I have fixed it. You can update the extension to latest version 9.1.0.0.

If you have any questions about Open SEO Stats,  you can also send email to pr [at] chromefans.org.

Open SEO Stats in Chrome Web Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-seo-statsformerly-pa/hbdkkfheckcdppiaiabobmennhijkknn

How to update: http://www.chromefans.org/chrome-tutorial/how-to-manually-update-chrome-extensions.htm